# Accessing + retrieving custom database in WordPress

Tags: customization, database

I am looking for something really simple(?). I am using WordPress as a CMS. I created a new page in which I added a form (questionnaire). Inside WordPress' database (the same database in which all WordPress data are), I created a new table called "ExampleTable".

Now I have 2 questions:

1) How can I insert data from the form into that custom table?
2) Is is "okay" to add a custom table (which has nothing to do with WP inside WordPress' database, or should I create a new database?)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is OK. And you can access this table with standard way, [throught wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

To insert data to your table use this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert( 
    'exampleTable', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1', 
        'column2' => 123 
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s', 
        '%d' 
    ) 
);
```

To breafly explain what this code mean. WordPress sanitizes values before inserting them into database (to prevent database being compromited by SQL injection.). First line defines table to inser value. Secon array contains col names and value being inserted. The third array contains type of value to insers. %s stands for string, %d stands for int (digit).

You can read more about $wpdb->prepare [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks). It is well explained in there.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Sorry, I am a real beginner. Could you please explaine what %s and %d stands for; and why I need to specify it?

Comment: I've updated the answer. But have a look to the codex, everything is well explained in there: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb